# HTML/CSS - 100% Height Not truly 100&

Tags: html, css, height

I seem to be constantly running into this problem, and I'm not sure where I'm making the mistake.

I have a `main-body div` that is holding a background-color that I want as the background of the page. Within the dive I've got a `section class` with the little sections that are going to be copied over and over again with just the content changed.

If you scroll to the bottom, you'll notice that the background of the main-body div isn't really 100% and leaves this white bar.  How might I go about fixing this?

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header
{
    height: 230px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0099CC;
    display: block;
}

#headerFixedWidth
{
    width: 85%;
    height: 230px;
    //border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav
{
    //border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 35px;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#mainBody
{
    background-color: #F1F4F9;
    width: 100%;
    //height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.left-content
{
    height: 550px;
    width: 581px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.title
{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 37px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4E5E6A;
    margin: 20px 30px;
    text-shadow: rgba(78, 94, 106, .2) .1px .1px 2px -1px;
}

.author-subline
{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4E5E6A;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.article-text
{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #4E5E6A;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 1.56;
}

.readMore
{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #4E5E6A;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="header">
   <div id="headerFixedWidth"></div>
</div>

<div id="mainBody">
 <section class="left-content">
   <p class="title">Minim perferendis placeat</p>
    <p class="author-subline">Minim perferendis placeat modi</p>
    <p class="article-text">Minim perferendis placeat modi, vitae porttitor exercitation dolorum duis atque ridiculus luctus earum!.</p> 
     <p class="readMore">Read More</p>
   </section>

 <section class="left-content">
   <p class="title">Minim perferendis placeat</p>
    <p class="author-subline">Minim perferendis placeat modi</p>
    <p class="article-text">Minim perferendis placeat modi, vitae porttitor exercitation dolorum duis atque ridiculus luctus earum!.</p> 
     <p class="readMore">Read More</p>
   </section>
 
 <section class="left-content">
   <p class="title">Minim perferendis placeat</p>
    <p class="author-subline">Minim perferendis placeat modi</p>
    <p class="article-text">Minim perferendis placeat modi, vitae porttitor exercitation dolorum duis atque ridiculus luctus earum!.</p> 
     <p class="readMore">Read More</p>
   </section>
 
 <section class="left-content">
   <p class="title">Minim perferendis placeat</p>
    <p class="author-subline">Minim perferendis placeat modi</p>
    <p class="article-text">Minim perferendis placeat modi, vitae porttitor exercitation dolorum duis atque ridiculus luctus earum!.</p> 
     <p class="readMore">Read More</p>
   </section>
</div>
```

Comment: The way you comment is wrong... It should be `/* */` and not `//`, unless you are using SCSS or some preprocessor. Also, the reason why they appear commented is, it is invalid and finally the browser doesn't know how to parse them. So it doesn't apply those rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the `#mainBody` having a `margin`:

[image: preview]

Just remove the `margin-bottom` and it will be alright.

```css
#mainBody {
  background-color: #F1F4F9;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;                    /* Do this... */
}
```

Comment: I removed the margin-bottom (not even sure how it got in there lol) and I tried duplicating the section a few more times and while the sections duplicate without problem, the background, even though it is 100% just stops half way down the page

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner Can you replicate it using [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) please? Would love to look at it.

Comment: Sure give me 5 min and I'll copy a link

Comment: never mind my friend.  I think it's just my code editor's preview function.  When I copied it into code pen it displays fine. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Ah... I was about to say Sublime Text. But brackets is good too.. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Yo do not need a margin at the body (I also don´t know why are you using this...):

```
#mainBody {
  background-color: #F1F4F9;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How is this answer better than mine? `:)` Just curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you just change the **#mainBody** CSS property *margin-bottom* you should be fine!

```css
#mainbody{
    background-color: #F1F4F9;
    width: 100%;
    //height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

To this

```css
#mainbody{
    background-color: #F1F4F9;
    width: 100%;
    //height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How is this answer better than mine? `:)` Just curious to know. And still you have a mistake in your answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar its not, I was on the page and wrote my answer and left the editor open for a while then submitted :p i didn't really see your answer

Comment: Okie dokie... `:)`